# Windows 8 update - Google chrome in full screen mode

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-update

Last night Windows 8 has updated my machine and now when I open my browser (Google Chrome) it opens in "Full screen mode", like before certain Windows apps would do. Now e.g. I don't see my taskbar when in my browser and when I ALT-TAB away the music playing from Youtube stops playing. How do I turn this thing off? I want Chrome to run as before.

Comment: Please don't swear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a setting for toggling between Windows 8 mode and standard mode.You'll find it right in the settings button.

Answer is right here:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/E09KAbShiRc

I don't mean to be *mean* but it's just about googling.

Comment: Thanks, I did "Google", but it seems like I was using the wrong keywords..

Comment: You can always choose for a correct answer ;)