# How to get full screen in Chrome?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome

I just bought a new Windows 8 laptop and so far I'm really happy with it. But for some reason my Google Chrome is missing a full-screen feature. I have the latest version, it just isn't there.

Please note, [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/611076/windows-8-update-google-chrome-in-full-screen-mode) is similar but my issue is that the full screen option doesn't appear, at all (in either the metro mode or normal mode).

Comment: Did you download Chrome from the official page or a third party page?

Comment: I downloaded it from the official page

Answer (score 4):

The full screen shortcut is <kbd>F11</kbd>

The reason this may happen is, it tries to set up the browser as an app (or Chrome tries to behave like an app) (which has different behaviours in regards to minimize/maximize, hence why no option to change screen size for example amongst other things)! So we have to tell Windows 8 (or at least Chrome) that it needs to be treated as a program. Click the menu button (the one with the three vertical lines) and then click `Relaunch Chrome on the desktop`.

Remember `Chrome will remember the mode you last used and will reopen in the same mode. For example, if you exit Chrome from your desktop, when you launch Chrome the next time, Chrome will open on your desktop even if you launch Chrome from the Start Screen.`

[More details](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2762879?hl=en-GB)

Comment: How do you put the keys (like this F11) into the KEY-Style feature?

Comment: F11 doesn't work either. When i click the 3 lines there's no relaunch Chrome on the desktop button. There is a relaunch in windows 8 mode option though, but that doesn't do anything

Comment: @AmirrezaNasiri see this http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6048/is-there-a-kbd-for-the-windows-key but the answer is `<kdb>F11</kbd>'

Comment: @Wouter, please try it (change to windows 8 mode), and then restart the machine... Just to see if it helps. Also, please make IE the default browser and see if the problem is then fixed in Chrome

Comment: Just restarted the computer. Still no difference. Also clicking switch to windows 8 mode doesn't seem to do that. It just restarts and when i click on the 3 lines again the switch to windows 8 option is still there

Comment: I can change between the Windows 8 mode and the desktop mode now. Still no Fullscreen mode though...

Comment: Nope, this person kinda has the opposite of my problem. I can switch beetween desktop and windows 8 mode countless times, but the full screen option just isn't there and F11 doesn't work either

Comment: Or is Windows 8 mode the best i can get? It does remove the taskbar, so that's a start...

Comment: I think you need to do some faffing here (sorry). Install it and install the previous version (or even just re-install). I'm suspicious you've got a Beta version or similar?

Comment: Also confirm you're not in any of the other modes, like Presentation mode (View>Enter Presentation Mode)